# I'm getting an error when comparing in text file with python

Tags: python

[X,Y Matrix list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik9W3.png)

In this matrix, like adding items such as 1x3,3x3,5x5 to the map, check each item according to the item id and if it is 1x3 and start from the starting coordinate, for example X:5 Y1, if the item is horizontal and it is , then push it to the y-axis once and to the x-axis 3 times. I would like to add the id I assigned and add the ones with the same id separately, for example, there are two items with item id 82, but one is number 1, the other is number 2 and 0. I want to compare the shortest path from the non-item squares by scanning them one by one.
but I'm having trouble reading the txt files with the dimensions of the items. I was reading it directly as .read() before and I noticed that the items were measuring incorrectly.

The code where I check the item sizes

```
def propsize(propid):

    path1x1 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x1.txt"
    path1x3 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x3.txt"
    path1x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x5.txt"
    path1x10 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x10.txt"
    path1x19 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x19.txt"
    path3x3 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/3x3.txt"
    path3x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/3x5.txt"
    path4x7 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/4x7.txt"
    path4x8 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/4x8.txt"
    path5x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/5x5.txt"
    path6x6 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/6x6.txt"
    path7x7 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/7x7.txt"
    path8x8 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/8x8.txt"
    path9x9 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/9x9.txt"
    path10x10 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/10x10.txt"
    path20x20 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/20x20.txt"

    p1x1 = open(path1x1,"r").readlines()
    p1x3 = open(path1x3,"r").readlines()
    p1x5 = open(path1x5,"r").readlines()
    p1x10 = open(path1x10,"r").readlines()
    p1x19 = open(path1x19,"r").readlines()
    p3x3 = open(path3x3,"r").readlines()
    p3x5 = open(path3x5,"r").readlines()
    p4x7 = open(path4x7,"r").readlines()
    p4x8 = open(path4x8,"r").readlines()
    p5x5 = open(path5x5,"r").readlines()
    p6x6 = open(path6x6,"r").readlines()
    p7x7 = open(path7x7,"r").readlines()
    p8x8 = open(path8x8,"r").readlines()
    p9x9 = open(path9x9,"r").readlines()
    p10x10 = open(path10x10,"r").readlines()
    p20x20 =  open(path20x20,"r").readlines()

    for p in p1x1:
            if propid == p:
                    print("1x1")
                    return "1:1"
    for p in p1x3:       
            if propid == p:
                    print("1x3")
                    return "1:3"
    for p in p1x5:        
            if propid == p:
                    print("1x5")
                    return "1:5"
    for p in p1x10:
            if propid == p:
                    print("1x10")
                    return "1:10"
    for p in p1x19:
            if propid == p:
                    print("1x19")
                    return "1:19"
    for p in p3x3:
            if propid == p:
                    print("3x3")
                    return "3:3"   
    for p in p3x5:
            if propid == p:
                    print("3x5")
                    return "3:5" 
    for p in p4x7:
            if propid == p:
                    print("4x7")
                    return "4:7"
    for p in p4x8:        
            if propid == p:
                    print("4x8")
                    return "4:8"
    for p in p5x5:
            if propid == p:
                    print("5x5")
                    return "5:5"
    for p in p6x6:
            if propid == p:
                    print("6x6")
                    return "6:6"
    for p in p7x7:
            if propid == p:
                    print("7x7")
                    return "7:7"
    for p in p8x8:
            if propid == p:
                    print("8x8")
                    return "8:8"
    for p in p9x9:
            if propid == p:
                    print("9x9")
                    return "9:9"
    for p in p10x10:        
            if propid == p:
                    print("10x10")
                    return "10:10"
    for p in p20x20:
            if propid == p:
                    print("20x20")
                    return "20:20"
    return "!:!"
```

The code where I add the items to the matrix

```
def fill_flats(pid, corx,cory,sizex,sizey,rot):


if rot == "h":
    yt = 0
    
    while yt < sizey:
        xt = 0
        while xt < sizex:
            global Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5 , Y6, Y7, Y8, Y9 , Y10, Y11, Y12 , Y13, Y14, Y15, Y16, Y17 , Y18, Y19, Y20
            exec ("Y{}[{}]={}".format(str(cory+xt),corx+yt,pid))

            xt +=1
        yt+=1    
if rot == "v":
    xt = 0
    
    while xt < sizex:
        yt = 0
        while yt < sizey:
            global Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5 , Y6, Y7, Y8, Y9 , Y10, Y11, Y12 , Y13, Y14, Y15, Y16, Y17 , Y18, Y19, Y20
            exec ("Y{}[{}]={}".format(str(cory+yt),corx+xt,pid))

            yt +=1
        xt+=1
```

And this is the error I get

```
 /Tructer/test.py", line 188, in importmap
  fill_flats(propanalyzed[o]["pnum"],int(propanalyzed[o] 
   ["cordinatesX"]),int(propanalyzed[o]["cordinatesY"]),int(propanalyzed[o] 
    ["X"]),int(propanalyzed[o]["Y"]),str(propanalyzed[o]["rotation"]))       
     ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '!'
```

size function returning: “!:!” where am i doing wrong:(

My full test.py code

```
from asyncio import queues
from http import cookies
import os
from posixpath import split
from textwrap import fill
import time
from typing_extensions import Self
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from rich.progress import track
xcursor =1
ycursor =1

title = Figlet(font='slant')
print(title.renderText('TRUCTER'))

Y1 =   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y2 =   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y3 =   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y4  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y5  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y6  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y7  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y8  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y9  =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y10 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y11 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y12 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y13 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y14 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y15 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y16 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y17 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y18 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y19 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y20 =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


def checklogged():
       
       
         
        for cookie in cookies:
                
            if cookie['name'] == "ltc_user":
                    print(cookie)
            
def propsize(propid):
        path1x1 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x1.txt"
        path1x3 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x3.txt"
        path1x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x5.txt"
        path1x10 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x10.txt"
        path1x19 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/1x19.txt"
        path3x3 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/3x3.txt"
        path3x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/3x5.txt"
        path4x7 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/4x7.txt"
        path4x8 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/4x8.txt"
        path5x5 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/5x5.txt"
        path6x6 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/6x6.txt"
        path7x7 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/7x7.txt"
        path8x8 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/8x8.txt"
        path9x9 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/9x9.txt"
        path10x10 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/10x10.txt"
        path20x20 = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/20x20.txt"

        p1x1 = open(path1x1,"r").readlines()
        p1x3 = open(path1x3,"r").readlines()
        p1x5 = open(path1x5,"r").readlines()
        p1x10 = open(path1x10,"r").readlines()
        p1x19 = open(path1x19,"r").readlines()
        p3x3 = open(path3x3,"r").readlines()
        p3x5 = open(path3x5,"r").readlines()
        p4x7 = open(path4x7,"r").readlines()
        p4x8 = open(path4x8,"r").readlines()
        p5x5 = open(path5x5,"r").readlines()
        p6x6 = open(path6x6,"r").readlines()
        p7x7 = open(path7x7,"r").readlines()
        p8x8 = open(path8x8,"r").readlines()
        p9x9 = open(path9x9,"r").readlines()
        p10x10 = open(path10x10,"r").readlines()
        p20x20 =  open(path20x20,"r").readlines()

        for p in p1x1:
                if propid == p:
                        print("1x1")
                        return "1:1"
        for p in p1x3:       
                if propid == p:
                        print("1x3")
                        return "1:3"
        for p in p1x5:        
                if propid == p:
                        print("1x5")
                        return "1:5"
        for p in p1x10:
                if propid == p:
                        print("1x10")
                        return "1:10"
        for p in p1x19:
                if propid == p:
                        print("1x19")
                        return "1:19"
        for p in p3x3:
                if propid == p:
                        print("3x3")
                        return "3:3"   
        for p in p3x5:
                if propid == p:
                        print("3x5")
                        return "3:5" 
        for p in p4x7:
                if propid == p:
                        print("4x7")
                        return "4:7"
        for p in p4x8:        
                if propid == p:
                        print("4x8")
                        return "4:8"
        for p in p5x5:
                if propid == p:
                        print("5x5")
                        return "5:5"
        for p in p6x6:
                if propid == p:
                        print("6x6")
                        return "6:6"
        for p in p7x7:
                if propid == p:
                        print("7x7")
                        return "7:7"
        for p in p8x8:
                if propid == p:
                        print("8x8")
                        return "8:8"
        for p in p9x9:
                if propid == p:
                        print("9x9")
                        return "9:9"
        for p in p10x10:        
                if propid == p:
                        print("10x10")
                        return "10:10"
        for p in p20x20:
                if propid == p:
                        print("20x20")
                        return "20:20"
        return "!:!"
def importmap():
        designfile = "/settings/design.txt"
        designParsedfile = "/settings/design_parsed.txt"
        path_d = os.getcwd()+designfile
        path_dp = os.getcwd()+designParsedfile
        propnumber = 1
        print('Design Analyzing...')
        with open(path_d) as f:
                propanalyzed = {}
                props = f.readline().replace(" ","").split(";")
                props.__delitem__(len(props)-1)
                pnumber = 1
                for prop in props:
                   
                        p = prop.split(",")
                        
                        ps = propsize(p[0].replace(" ",""))
                        p_size = ps.split(":")
                
                        propanalyzed[propnumber] = {
                                "propid"      : p[0],
                                "X"           : p_size[0],
                                "Y"           : p_size[1],
                                "cordinatesX" : int(p[1])+1,
                                "cordinatesY" : int(p[2])+1,
                                "rotation"    : p[3],
                                "pnum"        : pnumber
                        }
                        propnumber = propnumber+1
                        pnumber +=1
                pnumber = 1
                propnumber=1
        pathanalyzed = os.getcwd() + "/settings/PropSize/propanalyzed.txt"
        open(pathanalyzed, "a").write(str(propanalyzed) + "\n") 
        print('Map Visualation in Progress...')
        
        
        for o in propanalyzed:
                fill_flats(propanalyzed[o]["pnum"],int(propanalyzed[o]["cordinatesX"]),int(propanalyzed[o]["cordinatesY"]),int(propanalyzed[o]["X"]),int(propanalyzed[o]["Y"]),str(propanalyzed[o]["rotation"]))       
        

def move_x(a,b):
        global xcursor
        if a == "+":
                xcursor = xcursor + b
        elif a=="-":
                xcursor = xcursor - b
def move_y(a,b):
        global ycursor
        if a == "+":
                ycursor = ycursor + b
        elif a=="-":
                ycursor = ycursor - b
              
def fill_flats(pid, corx,cory,sizex,sizey,rot):
    

    if rot == "h":
        yt = 0
        
        while yt < sizey:
            xt = 0
            while xt < sizex:
                global Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5 , Y6, Y7, Y8, Y9 , Y10, Y11, Y12 , Y13, Y14, Y15, Y16, Y17 , Y18, Y19, Y20
                exec ("Y{}[{}]={}".format(str(cory+xt),corx+yt,pid))

                xt +=1
            yt+=1    
    if rot == "v":
        xt = 0
        
        while xt < sizex:
            yt = 0
            while yt < sizey:
                global Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5 , Y6, Y7, Y8, Y9 , Y10, Y11, Y12 , Y13, Y14, Y15, Y16, Y17 , Y18, Y19, Y20
                exec ("Y{}[{}]={}".format(str(cory+yt),corx+xt,pid))

                yt +=1
            xt+=1 
            



importmap()
pr = 1
mapppt = os.getcwd() + "/settings/mapp.txt"

while pr < 20:
        
        open(mapppt, 'a').write(str(str(Y1[pr])+"  | " + str(Y2[pr])+"  | " + str(Y3[pr])+"  | " + str(Y4[pr])+"  | " + str(Y5[pr])+"  | " + str(Y6[pr])+"  | " + str(Y7[pr])+"  | " + str(Y8[pr])+"  | " + str(Y9[pr])+"  | " + str(Y10[pr])+"  | " + str(Y11[pr])+"  | " + str(Y12[pr])+"  | " + str(Y13[pr])+"  | " + str(Y14[pr])+"  | " + str(Y15[pr])+"  | " + str(Y16[pr])+"  | " + str(Y17[pr])+"  | " + str(Y18[pr])+"  | " + str(Y19[pr])+"  | " + str(Y20[pr])+"  | ")+ '\n')                   
        pr +=1
```

And example propsize file

```
5
6
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
80
81
82
84
```

And example item before processing(82 is item number , 0 is x cordinate and 1 is y cordinate and "v" is rotation type

```
82,0,1,v;
```

Comment: What does the first block of code have to do with the second block of code?  I don't see that the latter code calls `propsize()`.

Comment: first block returning sizex and sizey variables for second block

Comment: propanalyzed[propnumber] = {
                                "propid"      : p[0],
                                "X"           : p_size[0],
                                "Y"           : p_size[1],
                                "cordinatesX" : int(p[1])+1,
                                "cordinatesY" : int(p[2])+1,
                                "rotation"    : p[3],
                                "pnum"        : pnumber
                        }

Comment: prop id original item id for 1x3,1x5,3x3..... txt. if 1x3 txt contains propid, i writing sizey and sizex to propanalyzed dictionary

Comment: and pnum occurs according to the order the item is added to the propanalyzed dictionary. It is the pnum variable that I want to write to the matrix

Comment: Well, I can't see quite where it's happening, as your code isn't complete (what is calling `fill_flats`?), but it seems to me that your `propsize` function is returning `!:!` and then something is breaking that apart and treating one of the `!` as thought it is an integer.  But of course, it is not.  The error is a bit strange because it says "invalid literal", which only occurs if your code is wrong (not your data).  But here, you blur the line between code and data in your use of`exec`. It seems to me that you're somehow generating and executing code that places `!` where a number should be.

Comment: I can't say this with certainty because again, I can't see or understand exactly what you're doing, but 99.9% of the time, you don't want to be using `exec` for doing the kinds of things it appears that your code is doing.  It really only makes sense to use `exec` in cases where some user or other system has given you Python code to be incorporated into your program.  I'm assuming that you're a novice Python programmer.  If so, then it's even more certain that you shouldn't be using `exec`.  The `exec` function almost shouldn't exist at all in Python because it is usually misused.

Comment: I totally agree with @CryptoFool, avoid using exec and eval when you don't really need them. Instead of Y1, Y2, Y3 I would create a matrix Y[][].

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO saw it better than I did.  You want just what they said...a single 2-d array (a matrix) Y`[][]`.

Comment: @CryptoFool yes i am a novice Python programmer what you say is very valuable to me :)

Comment: @CesurAlgos - totally cool.  no problem.  You have just happened upon a kind of programming that hits a nerve.  Any of us who have been around for a while know that we need to get you off of this way of doing things IMMEDIATELY, for your own sanity.  `exec` and lots of global variables are two things that throw up big red flags right away, especially when they're used together like this.  It's going to take you some time, but you'll be best served by rewriting your code to work with a 2-d matrix. I can almost guarantee you that you'll thank us later :)

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Thank you very much, I didn't know that(Y[][]), I tried to add it as a dictionary, but it didn't work properly and I want to print on the fly the items on the map and the current cursor (that is, the frame where the player is at that moment:)

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer, let me write...

Comment: What I think you really want is to use something like NumPy.  That's not something I've done as I haven't needed to do this sort of thing in Python, but NumPy, or possibly Pandas or some other package that is meant to process structured data like this will do you wonders.  - but maybe @FLAK-ZOSO can set you up with straight Python, lol.

Comment: For sure a NumPy 2D array would be a better choice, but I've never used NumPy so much... pure Python should work too

Comment: @CesurAlgos - Does FLAK's answer get you thinking and moving in the right direction?  I gotta go to bed...it's after midnight here...but I'd be happy to help you to rework your code and get this right.  I wish I better understood what you're really trying to do.  But we can get there.  Programming's been really good to me.  I want to give back and help new programmers.  I'll help if you want.  Or just keep asking questions here.  That you put as much work into this as you obviously did is really cool.  Don't get discouraged.

Comment: What's more I don't see any file.close(), better using the with/as syntax for reading files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `ValueError`, but the problem with your code isn't this.

---

```
exec ("Y{}[{}]={}".format(str(cory+xt),corx+yt,pid))
```

**This** is the problem. Creating `Y1` `Y2` `Y3` ... `Y20` is a very bad idea, try something like this instead:

```
Y = []
for _ in range(20):
    Y.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

then you can access it this way:

```
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(10): # Instead of 10 put the lenght of your inner lists
        Y[i][j]
```

Comment: Nice!  This is exactly the right idea.  I had to look this up, but I think the canonical way to create an empty matrix is `matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 
` where the inputs are `w, h`, the width and height of the matrix you want.  Then you access `matrix` just like shown in this answer.

Comment: this looks great, I'll try it when I get home, but before I changed the read() part to readlines(), it didn't give an error, but it was returning wrong values, and while adding some of them in the correct number on the map, for example, adding 1x3 items to 3 squares one after the other, while adding some 1x3 items to a single flat.

Comment: readlines() returns a list with the content of the file split by newlines. It's near the same thing as read().split('\n')